# How to do custom filtering with Datatables and server-side processing

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using [Datatables](http://datatables.net) to display tabular data in my Web application, and have configured it to make use of [server-side processing](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side), i.e. query the server via AJAX for filtered data. I want to filter according to additional parameters that are specific to my application, i.e. corresponding to some user options (f.ex. via a checkbox in the UI). How do I make DataTables pass these additional filter parameters to the server?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is to employ DataTables' [fnServerParams](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) option, which allows you to add custom parameters to be sent in the XMLHttpRequest sent to the server. For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#example').dataTable({
    "bProcessing": true,
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "/IndexXhr",
    "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
        var includeUsuallyIgnored = $("#include-checkbox").is(":checked");
        aoData.push({name: "includeUsuallyIgnored", value: includeUsuallyIgnored});
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: you can redraw datatable by adding event function to your element:`$('#id').change( function() { oTable.fnDraw(); } );` where oTable is a variable with your datable object `oTable = $('#itemsTable').dataTable({....})`

Answer (score 17):

**This answer is updated for version 1.10.6**

This is now can be done using the [ajax](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option.

Sample code

```
 $table.dataTable({
            "ajax":  {
                "url": "example.com/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "data": function(d) {
                    d.Foo = "bar";
                    d.Bar = "foo";
                    d.FooBar = "foobarz";
                }
            },
            "serverSide":true,
        });
```

Foo, Bar and FooBar will be posted as Form Data as additional parameters along with other existing ones like *draw, start, length,* etc so depending on your server side language you can read them accordingly.

In a real life scenerio, you would probably have a Search button and some input, you can trigger the filtering process by calling

```
        var table = $table.DataTable();
        table.ajax.reload();
```

when the button is clicked.

Comment: this worked for me, also it should be: table.api().ajax.reload(). for dataTable(); *note the lowercase*

Answer (score 4):

Finally did it after spending hours!

I will post the complete method here for everyone's help.

One needs to use `fnServerParams` option, which allows adding custom parameters to be sent in the XMLHttpRequest sent to the server. For example:

Here is the coffescript I used:

```
jQuery ->
  table = $('#logs').dataTable
    bProcessing: true
    bServerSide: true
    sAjaxSource: $('#logs').data('source')
    fnServerParams: (aoData) ->
      applicationName = $("#applicationName").val()
      aoData.push
        name: "applicationName"
        value: applicationName

      return

  $("#applicationName").on "change", ->
    table.fnDraw()
    return
```

My HTML file contains the input element with id `applicationName`. Note the `fnDraw()` element I used to enable redraw request whenever input value changes.

Comment: How does this technique differ from the one in my answer, except it is in CoffeeScript?

Comment: Your answer does not tell how to bind the html element with event that will redraw the table. More specifically, the `fnDraw()` functionality. This method does not seem very useful to me without this.

Comment: But binding to an HTML element has nothing to do with the question. I can vouch that my answer is useful without your functionality, since it solved my original problem (my being the author of this question).

Comment: This is exactly the reason I upvoted your answer. I added it because many people ( like me and the one who commented on your answer) are looking for both. This answer will save some time for them. Still I can delete my answer if you want.

Comment: I think it'd be much less confusing if you asked a question about what you're trying to do, and linked to its answer here instead.

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic parameter, This one is working for me, seems best solution

```
t = $("#tbl_SearchCustomer").DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    info: true,
    ajax: {
        url: '../Data/SearchCustomer',
        data: function (data) {
            data.CustomerCategoryID = $("#CustomerCategoryID").val(); // dynamic parameter
            delete data.columns;
        }
    },
    deferRender: true,
    columns: [
        { "data": "FullName" },            
    ],       
    dom: 'lfrtip'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
     table = $('#okmorders').DataTable( {
        // "ajax": 'http://cdpaha2.dev/admin/organizations/okm_orders'
    serverSide: true,
    "paging":   true,
    "searching":  false ,
        // "info":     false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        // "iDisplayLength":50,
        // "aaSorting": [],
        // "oLanguage": { "sEmptyTable": "No orders present " } ,
        "aoColumnDefs" : [
          { 'bSortable' : false, 'aTargets' : [ 6 ]}
    ],

   //  "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
   //    aoData.push({name: "includeUsuallyIgnored"});
   //  },
    ajax: {
          url: 'yoururl.json' ,
          type: 'POST',
      data:
      {
       'startDate':function(){return $("#startDate").val(); },
       'endDate': function(){return $("#endDate").val(); } ,
       'placedBy':function(){return $("#placedBy").val(); },
       'customer_po': function(){return $("#customer_po").val(); } ,
       'customer_ref': function(){return $("#customer_ref").val(); }
      }
    },
    } );
```